# Ruby on Rails no such column: authentication.provider: Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I was following this tutorial on Omniauth: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?view=asciicast

I keep getting this error:

> no such column: authentication.provider:

Now the **main thing** I want to know is why "provider" isn't being accepted.  It exists in the class... the authentications database exists... so why is it saying it isn't there?

Here's my authentications controller:

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def index
        @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
    end

    def create
        @user = User.where(authentication: auth).first_or_create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'])
        self.current_user = @user
        # auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] current_user.authentications.create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'])
        flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
        redirect_to authentications_url
    end

    def auth
        request.env['omniauth.auth']
    end

    def destroy
        @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
        @authentication.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
        redirect_to authentications_url
    end
end
```

I can assure you I have a model called authentication and that this model has a provider and uid field.  I've also tried  where(authentications: auth) and where(auth: auth)
each with no luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

authentication.rb (model)

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :create, :destroy, :index, :provider, :uid, :user_id
belongs_to :user
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

I'm basically attempting to adapt this tutorial to rails 3.2.

The original line from the tutorial is commented out above.

**UPDATE 3** 
Here is the entire first line of error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: authentication.provider: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "authentication"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "authentication"."uid" = '2222222' AND "authentication"."info" = '--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash

Hate to be a burden... but the clock's really ticking, my ass is on the line, and I'm about to go completely insane trying to figure this out. If you can tell me just why provider isn't being accepted I'm sure I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Does your `Authentication` model have `provider` attribute?  Please show us the annotation of your `Authentication` model.

Comment: Please post your error backtrace if you assure us that the model `Authentication` has `provider` attribute.

Comment: Updated with my authentication model.

Comment: I think this is exactly what you're looking for, follow this tutorial http://blog.railsrumble.com/2010/10/08/intridea-omniauth/

Comment: That one is from the same year (2010) as the other guide I was following.  Apparently some of that stuff is deprecated (for example "find by" is now "first.or.create").  I tried that guide and got even weirder errors. Specifically all I want to know is why provider isn't being accepted.

Comment: This is the tutorial I was following http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

your create action has not sense

`User.where(authentication: auth)` converts to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE authentication = a_hash`

You shoul do something like

```
auth1 = Authentication.where(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid']).first
if !auth1.nil?
  current_user = auth.user
else
  user = User.new
  user.authentications.build(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid'])
  user.save!
  current_user = user
end
```

Comment: With this I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Umm... Hello? :)  Any idea why it says undefined method "nil"? I get that whenever I try to use an "if" statement for some odd reason...

Comment: auth exists? I've changed the answer to use a different var name

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just adding a record in the `authentications` table, I am unable to understand why you are reassigning `this.current_user`.  Also is `current_user` a helper method or a member, if it's a member where is it declared?

Don't you just want to create an authentication for the current user as such?:

```
def create
    current_user.authentications.first_or_create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
end
```

This finds the first authentication record by provider and uid, if not found then creates that authentication record.

Also by that error, I hope you have figured out the answer to this question:

> Now the main thing I want to know is why "provider" isn't being
>   accepted. It exists in the class... the authentications database
>   exists... so why is it saying it isn't there?

It is because you are calling `first_or_create()` on `User` object, not `Authentication`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue recently. At first I thought I had forgotten to add a provider column to users table, but that wasn't it.
This is how I eventually solved it:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth["provider"], uid: auth["uid"]).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
    user.logo = auth["info"]["image"]
    # if you use confirmable, since facebook validates emails
    # skip confirmation emails
    user.skip_confirmation!
  end
end
```

auth is a hash like the one below, so instead of auth.provider, I used auth["provider"] etc:

```
omniauth.auth: {"provider"=>"facebook", "uid"=>"11111111111111", "info"=>{"email"=>"some@email.com", "image"=>"http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/11111111111111/picture"}, "credentials"=>{"token"=>"sometoken", "expires_at"=>1506680013, "expires"=>true}, "extra"=>{"raw_info"=>{"email"=>"some@email.com", "id"=>"11111111111111"}}}
```